# Error : Expected expression before 'struct'

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I cant figure out what I am doing wrong here / how do I fix it. It is giving me an indication of expecting an expression before struct on line 90. Can somebody help me out with this problem?

I want to print a structure that is in a function, but because of the 2 arguments behind it I cant find a proper way to code it. The other functions do work fine, but when I add this one it all goes wrong.

```
   #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

struct geboorteDatum
{
    int geboortedag;
    int geboortemaand;
    int geboortejaar;
};

struct Persoon
{
    struct geboorteDatum;
    char naam[20];
};

void    printPersonen(struct Persoon *pt, int persoonCount);
void    scanPersonen(int persoonCount);
int     startMenu(void);

int main()
{

startMenu();

}

void    printPersonen(struct Persoon *pt, int persoonCount)
{

    printf("Gegevens persoon 1 : ");


    printf("\n%s",pt[persoonCount].naam);
    printf("\n%d",pt[persoonCount].geboortedag);
    printf("\n%d",pt[persoonCount].geboortemaand);
    printf("\n%d",pt[persoonCount].geboortejaar);
    printf("\n");


}

void    scanPersonen(int persoonCount)
{

    struct Persoon pt[100];

    printf("Voer Gegevens persoon . : \n");

    scanf("%s", pt[persoonCount].naam);
    scanf("%d", &pt[persoonCount].geboortedag);
    scanf("%d", &pt[persoonCount].geboortemaand);
    scanf("%d", &pt[persoonCount].geboortejaar);

}

int     startMenu(void)
{

int keuze = 0;

int persoonCount = 0;
int * p1 = &persoonCount;

    do
    {

        printf("MENU \n");
        printf("1 : Voer een persoon in \n");
        printf("2 : Toon alle geboortedatums \n");
        printf("3 : Toon de jongste persoon \n");
        printf("4 : Toon verjaardagen in een maand \n");
        printf("0 : Einde \n\n");

        printf("Maak een keus : ");

        scanf("%d", &keuze);
        printf("\n");

            if(keuze == 1)
            {
                persoonCount++;
                scanPersonen(persoonCount);

            }

            else if(keuze == 2)
            {
                printPersonen(struct Persoon *pt, int persoonCount);
            }

            else if(keuze == 3)
            {
                printf("jo3");
            }

            else if(keuze == 4)
            {
                printf("%d",persoonCount);
            }

            else
            {
                printf("Deze keus is niet mogelijk, kies opnieuw \n\n");
                return startMenu();
            }

} while (keuze > 0);

return persoonCount;

}
```

Comment: `struct Persoon` has no members named `geboortedag`, `geboortemaand`, and `geboortejaar`. You need to name the member variable of type `struct geboorteDatum` in `Persoon` and use it then.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in:

```
struct Persoon
{
    struct geboorteDatum;
    char naam[20];
};
```

that `struct geboorteDatum` specifies a type, but no member name! You can fix that by adding one `struct geboorteDatum d;`

Then in your print and scan functions replace

```
printf("\n%d",pt[persoonCount].geboortedag);
```

with

```
printf("\n%d",pt[persoonCount].d.geboortedag);
```

But even better would be to change the `struct geboorteDatum` to

```
struct Date {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
}
```

as a birthday is just a date. you do not need a special type to represent birthdays.

Then `struct Persoon` becomes:

```
struct Person {
     struct Data birthday;
     char name[20];
};
```

And the print statements become

```
printf("\n%d", pt[persoonCount].birthday.day);
```

(And translate all code to English for easier sharing. I could understand the dutch part, but most people cannot.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Its really helpfull

Answer (score 0):

*Cough*

well....

```
 printPersonen(struct Persoon *pt, int persoonCount);
```

means you are declaring a prototype, and in that context is incorrect. May be it should be:

```
 printPersonen(pt, persoonCount);
```

Comment: You should point to the place where it is incorrect. This declaration occurs not only once in the code.

Comment: Sorry if Im doing it wrong, but the error of the code is only on line 90 (else if (keuze == 2)).

Comment: @DanielLangr Well, it looks this user is a student learning the language, and so, pointing the concept error and letting him do the rest it wold be more didactic for him, doesn't it? but anyway you are right, as is a share place, i should give full responses.